Given an example html snippet that I cannot change, is there a **CSS only** approach to make text before <br> as bold and after <br> as normal?
I have this html
<div class="html-input goto-card-label">Header <br> Subtitle</div>

CSS is making the entire label bold:
.goto-card-label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

Is there a CSS only approach to make the text after the <br> tag as font-weight: normal; without changing the html at all?
Note: I likely cannot use the content css property since the text will not always be what I put in the example.

You can approach your problem using ::first-line pseudo-element to the first line of the text within div element.


.goto-card-label::first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div class="html-input goto-card-label">Header <br> Subtitle</div>




Try following ways
you can use span tag with inline CSS Styling
<div class="html-input goto-card-label">Header <br>  <span style="font-weight: normal;">Subtitle</span></div>


Thank you, but please note in the question that I cannot change the html.
